# Embedding JAR Game into Wordpress website

Tags: java, wordpress

Hello I am a designer not a programmer. My brother programmed a game for me a while ago with eclipse. It has the extension JAR. I want to embed this game into my wordpress website but I dont know how. I only have the `.exe` and the `.jar` file of the game but not the code.

How this can be possible without going into deep programming?

Comment: Modern browsers no longer support Java applets.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That is sad. I try to find another way then.

Comment: If you have the JAR file there is a very good chance you have the code. It is simply and archive. Expand it and see if the source is intact.

Answer (score 0):

"The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using Java Web Start. A JWS app. can be launched from a link on a web site" [1]

[1] **Andrew Thompson**,  [Publishing a .jar game online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581531/publishing-a-jar-game-online)
Wiki: https://www.java.com/es/download/faq/java_webstart.xml